# how to display array variable outside a loop

Tags: php

Hello I have code like this

```
                <div class="table-wrapper-2">

                    <!--Table-->
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead class="mdb-color lighten-4">
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">Name</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">Surname</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">Country</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">City</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">Position</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">Age</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">Position</th>
                                <th class="th-lg">Position</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $a='TAJUL';
                           $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT def_usr,problem,solution,def_date,closed_date FROM hd_report  where def_usr=:num order by def_date DESC');
                       oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":num", $a);
                          oci_execute($stid);
                       $count = 0;

                                 while (($row = oci_fetch_row($stid)) != false) {
                                   $def_usr=$row[0];
                                   $problem=$row[1];
                                   $solution=$row[2];
                                   $def_date=$row[3];
                                   $closed_date=$row[4];
                                   $count=$count+1;
                             ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><?php echo $count ?></th>
                                <td><?php echo $def_usr ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $def_date ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $closed_date ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $problem ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <button type="button" href="#myModalDelete"
                                                    data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"
                                                    data-problem="<?php $problem?>">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Detail
                                            </button>
                                            </td>           


        <?php
        }
        ?>      
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>

                </table>
                    <!--Table-->

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Start Modal for Delete -->
        <div id="myModalDelete" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Alert message !!!</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
                        <form method="post" action="view_detailquestion">

                            <h3>Are you sure you want to View this question ?</h3>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>ID</label> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                         name="problem" value="<?php echo $problem?>" readonly>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="action"
                                value="view">view</button>

                        </form>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My problem is i want to echo $problem outside the loop.when i do that it only contains 1 value only.So was thinking is there any solution for me to caryy the $problem outside the bracket.like we all can see in **start modal for delete** i try to echo $problem but the result is liked i said just carry only 1 value only not the array...
so i was hoping that you guys can be my guide for me thank....

Comment: Did you get the solution for your problem?

Comment: no yet.... rigth now i still trying all the solution that are given...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make $problem an array then. Change the line to `$problems[] = $row[1];`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
      var problem_statement = $(this).data('problem');
      $(".modal-body #problemText").val( problem_statement );
      $("#myModalDelete").modal('show');
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="problemText" type="text" class="form-control" name="problem" value="" readonly>
```

Can you try this using some javascript. It seems you need this $problem in your modal popup? IMO add 'id' to your button, attach click event listener in javascript and in callback set data using in modal popup.

Comment: can yu give me more detail.... actually like this i try to display data in table and the user click any data using a button  so i will pop up more detail about the data without turn tu other pages so decided to use modal for it....sry i am asking a lot...i was a beginner in this field i dont have others partner or senior that can guide me thank you for yur support

Comment: @jens not an issue, It's a good approach. Sry for replying late, use this :

Comment: Going to edited my post. See if that helps then let me know your outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
$problem=array();
while (($row = oci_fetch_row($stid)) != false) {
  $problem[]=$row[1];
}

foreach($var in $problem){
  echo $var . "<br />"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are overriding the previous value while adding data to $problem variable. so you have to create array for this & need to append next value to existing array rather than overriding. 
Example:

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_row($stid)) != false) {
      $def_usr[]     =$row[0];
      $problem[]     =$row[1];
      $solution[]    =$row[2];
      $def_date[]    =$row[3];
      $closed_date[] =$row[4];
      $count=$count+1;
}
```

In this while loop you will get all array of `$problem`. If you want to display at another place then you have use `foreach loop`.

Example:

```
if(!empty($problem)) {
    foreach($problem as $value ) {
       echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() what its mean?

Comment: if $problem is empty & are using in `foreach()` that time this error came. if you want to remove this error then refer second condition.

Comment: I updated my code to remove the Invalid argument issue.

Comment: it done! but the output was not like i want thank you for your support.....but the best solution rigth know i thing was using javascript....